Configuring Next.js App with PM2 to Run on Domain Name Instead of IP Address on Webuzo Server
I am deploying a Next.js application on a Webuzo server, and I am running into issues getting my application to serve on my domain name (e.g., mowarrd.sa) instead of the server's IP address.
Here's a summary of what I've done so far:
Deployment:
I uploaded my Next.js project to the Webuzo server.
I ran npm install and npm run build successfully.
Starting the Application:
I am using PM2 to manage my application with the command:
bash
pm2 start npm --name "mowarrd" -- start
The application starts and is accessible via the server’s IP address but not through my domain name.
Domain Configuration:
My domain mowarrd.sa is correctly pointing to my server’s IP address via an A record.
Web Server Configuration:
I am using Apache on Webuzo. I attempted to set up a reverse proxy to forward requests from my domain to the port on which my Next.js app is running.
Here’s the configuration I added to /etc/httpd/conf.d/mowarrd.sa.conf:
apache
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mowarrd.sa
DocumentRoot /home/mowarrd/public_html
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

<Directory /home/mowarrd/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>


I restarted Apache after making changes:
bash
sudo systemctl restart httpd
Problem:
Despite these configurations, my Next.js application is still not accessible via http://mowarrd.sa. It only works when accessed via the server's IP address.
Questions:
What could be the issue with my current setup that prevents the application from being accessible via my domain name?
Are there any additional configurations or steps I might be missing to properly route traffic to my Next.js app using PM2 and Apache?
Could there be any issues with my PM2 configuration or the way Apache is handling the reverse proxy?
Any guidance or additional steps to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
I attempted to set up a reverse proxy to forward requests from my domain to the port on which my Next.js app is running.
Here’s the configuration I added to /etc/httpd/conf.d/mowarrd.sa.conf:
apache
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mowarrd.sa
DocumentRoot /home/mowarrd/public_html
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

<Directory /home/mowarrd/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>


I restarted Apache after making changes:
bash
sudo systemctl restart httpd
Problem:
Despite these configurations, my Next.js application is still not accessible via http://mowarrd.sa. It only works when accessed via the server's IP address.
